# Filter dates from related model fields

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to filter my `Produto` by some related model fields. How do I do that inside filters.Filterset?

In **views.py**:

```python
class ProdutoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Produto
        fields = {
            'codigo_de_barras': ['contains'],
            'nome': ['contains'],
            'estoque__ultima_entrada':['exact'], # estoque is the related model and ultima_entrada is the related model field
            'estoque__ultima_saida':['exact'] # estoque is the related model and ultima_saida is the related model field
        }
```

`Estoque` model in **models.py**:

```python
class Estoque(models.Model):   
    produto = models.OneToOneField(
        Produto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='estoque')
    quantidade = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0, 
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)], 
        error_messages={'Erro':'A quantidade deve ser positiva'})
    ultima_entrada = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    ultima_saida = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the above code doing or not doing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.